# hardware clock is set but date command is displayed wrong date and time

Tags: linux, time, date

I am setting date with **settimeofday** function my hardware clock is set perfectly but when i execute date command it shows me wrong date and time.

but if i reboot the system than it show me proper date.

how to resolve this issue without reboot ?

Comment: Maybe ntpd automatically set the time for you?

Comment: In my system i don't have ntpd as my system running with customized embedded linux.

Comment: What does "wrong date and time" mean? A nonsensical value? A few hours off exactly? Always off the same amount?

Comment: wrong value means previous set date and time is showing that is not same as hardware clock

Answer (score 0):

You need to export TZ variable for changing system time when it is not setted by default with your function.

Steps:
1. Create link of your time zone file to /etc/localtime
2. export TZ=/etc/localtime

May it helps you...